# C# Discord Bot Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord

I'm trying make a discord bot but I have issues connecting to the discord API. I'm using visual studio community 2019. I started this project using the .net core console app template. My .net core version is 2.2. I have followed several tutorials and even pulled some sample bots from git and they all give me the same `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException` unhandled exception error.

I did installed the Discord.Net nuget package, version 2.1.1, at first I was confused because I thought I wasn't dealing with jsons at all but then realised that the discord.net nuget package also installs `newtonsoft.json` version 11.0.2. I tried installing that package to see if that fixed my issue, but it didn't, I tried installing version 11.0.2 as well as 12.0.2 (latest version at the time of this post).

When running the app, my program stops and visual studio points at my static void main function.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
```

for this particular attempt at making a discord bot, I was following this guide: https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/first-bot.html

That article points out that if any exceptions are thrown in the async functions, they will be thrown all the way back up to the first non-async method which is the main method. So does that mean that the error is in my MainAsync function?

The exact error if I let the app crash is this:

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

This is my only file:

```cs
using System;
using Discord;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace Bot
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient Client;

        static void Main() => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            Client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            Client.Log += Log;

            //This is my discord bot token
            var token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await Client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting that `newtonsoft.json` if I myself am not dealing with json files and what I can do to get rid of this error? 
I appreciate any help. This is also my first time posting a question in stack overflow so if I'm not doing something right as far as asking questions please let me know.

Comment: It looks like Newtonsoft.Json is being asked to parsed HTML rather than JSON

Comment: For my last bot I started with this example: https://github.com/Aux/Discord.Net-Example

Answer (score 0):

To track down errors, I suggest wrapping each call in a try/catch block. Then log the location the error happened.

```
using System;
using Discord;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace Bot
{
    class Program
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient Client;

        static void Main() => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            try{
            Client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            Client.Log += Log;
            }catch(Exception ex){log("Error in init:"); throw ex;}
            //This is my discord bot token
            var token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            try{
            await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            }catch(Exception ex){log("Error during login"); throw ex;}
            try{
            await Client.StartAsync();
            }catch(ex){log("Error starting client"); throw ex;
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }
        private Task log(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }            
        private Task Log(LogMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

It is also recommended to include filenames and line #s in the messages as the project size grows.

JSON seems to be used as part of the API communicating with discord.
https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro
I see references is several of the topics there including messages from errors. It could be that you are getting some http error such as a 404 that includes an html response instead of expected json, thus why the error suggests an unexpected '<' as in <html>...</html> instead of { as in {...} though this is just a hunch.

Comment: To track down errors it's easier to turn on "break when thrown" for all exceptions, then you get the debugger stopping as soon as the error occurs. In some regards adding exception handlers makes the process harder, I find

Comment: Simply use a breakpoint and step through the code using the debugger, line by line. Adding a try/catch around every single call is a bit excessive.

Comment: I'd recommend logging the exception, perhaps with the standard logging in .NET. Also, you should use throw without the ex, so you don't unwind the call stack. The exception should have the filename, line, and position on the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

your code work perfectly. i just inserted my token an the bot started. Check if your token is right and maybe make the token a string